# React Add event DOMContentLoaded with useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, materialize

I am trying to add add an event listener to element after DOM is loaded in order to use Materialize CSS's Floating Action Button.

See code below, the effect function is fired, but the handleContentLoaded function is not. The component renders without errors.

What is missing here ? Is this the correct way to use this effect ?

```
  const handleContentLoaded = () => {
    console.log("handleContentLoaded fired");
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".fixed-action-btn");
    var instances = M.FloatingActionButton.init(elems, {});
    console.log("instances", instances);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("using effect");
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", handleContentLoaded);
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try remove addEventListener, useEffect runs after all the elements of the page is rendered correctly, you don't need any listener for that:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("using effect");
  handleContentLoaded();
}, []);
```